# Unable to put button along with the google map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, markerclusterer

So, basically i was trying to put a button on top of my map fragment but it doesn't seems to work despite the map working completely fine. Even after extensively searching Google, I couldn't find an executable answer.

Here's my map fragment-

```
public class Tab1 extends SupportMapFragment implements
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener, OnMapReadyCallback,
        ClusterManager.OnClusterClickListener<MyItem>,
        ClusterManager.OnClusterInfoWindowClickListener<MyItem>,
        ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<MyItem> {

    InputStream inputstream;
    BufferedReader reader;
    String title;
    GoogleMap map;
    AutoCompleteTextView actv;
    Map<String, String> moviemap;
    List<MyItem> items = new ArrayList<MyItem>();
    String subtitle;
    String floor;
    String type;
    Double lat;
    Double lng;
    int len;
    int arraylength;
    ClusterManager<MyItem> mClusterManager;
    List<Map<String, String>> moviedata;
    JSONArray jsonArray;
    JSONObject jsonObject;
    String m;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mCurrentLocation;

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(getActivity(), getMap());
        getMap().setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
        getMap().setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);
        mClusterManager
                .setOnClusterClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterClickListener<MyItem>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onClusterClick(final Cluster<MyItem> cluster) {
                        getMap().animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                                cluster.getPosition(), (float) Math.floor(getMap()
                                        .getCameraPosition().zoom + 2)), 300,
                                null);
                        return true;
                    }
                });

        try {
            inputstream = getResources().getAssets().open("map.json");
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream));
            m = reader.toString();
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line);
            }
            m = total.toString();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        moviedata = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(m);
            jsonArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("map");
            arraylength = jsonArray.length();
            len = arraylength;

            for (int i = 0; i < arraylength; i++) {
                moviemap = new HashMap<>();
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                title = jsonChildNode.optString("title");
                subtitle = jsonChildNode.optString("subtitle");
                floor = jsonChildNode.optString("floor");
                type = jsonChildNode.optString("type");
                lat = jsonChildNode.optDouble("latitude");
                lng = jsonChildNode.optDouble("longitude");
                moviemap.put("A", title);
                moviemap.put("B", subtitle);
                moviemap.put("C", floor);
                moviemap.put("D", type);
                moviemap.put("E", lat.toString());
                moviemap.put("F", lng.toString());
                moviedata.add(moviemap);
                Double lat1 = Double.parseDouble(moviedata.get(i).get("E"));
                Double lng1 = Double.parseDouble(moviedata.get(i).get("F"));
                items.add(new MyItem(lat1, lng1, moviedata.get(i).get("A"), moviedata.get(i).get("B")));
            }

            mClusterManager.addItems(items);
            mClusterManager.setRenderer(new MyClusterRenderer(getActivity(), getMap(), mClusterManager));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        initListeners();
    }

    private void initListeners() {
        getMap().setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);


    }

    private void removeListeners() {
        if (getMap() != null) {
            getMap().setOnInfoWindowClickListener(null);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        removeListeners();
    }

    private void initCamera(Location location) {
        CameraPosition position = CameraPosition.builder()
                .target(new LatLng(28.75007207311156, 77.11772996932268))
                .zoom(18f)
                .bearing(0.0f)
                .tilt(40f)
                .build();

        getMap().animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(position), null);

        getMap().setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        getMap().setTrafficEnabled(true);
        getMap().setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        getMap().getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }


    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        initCamera(mCurrentLocation);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        //handle play services disconnecting if location is being constantly used
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        //Create a default location if the Google API Client fails. Placing location at Googleplex
        mCurrentLocation = new Location("");
        mCurrentLocation.setLatitude(28.7499);
        mCurrentLocation.setLongitude(77.1170);
        initCamera(mCurrentLocation);
    }


    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(
            Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onClusterClick(Cluster<MyItem> cluster) {


        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClusterInfoWindowClick(Cluster<MyItem> cluster) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onClusterItemClick(MyItem myItem) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here's my xml-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `FrameLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` just like below.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView 
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

---

[image]

Comment: I have edited the answer already, including the frame layout you suggested. But the answer does no good to me. Well, another thing that I noticed is that, I haven't used the oncreateview method in my Java file. As a result the XML is not inflated. So an answer along that line might prove to be helpful.